# Adobe Target and AEM mbox error - can not read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: adobe, aem, targeting

i am having difficulties in integrating adobe target with AEM 
AEM 6.3.1 ( 6.3 with Service Pack 1)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
>       at Object.showDefaultMboxContent
>   [image]

Comment: are you using at.js or mbox.js as your target library? If you are using at.js, mboxFactoryDefault is not supported there.

Comment: I am using default mbox.js